'npm run dev' result: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/ddev/project-name/node_modules/@vue/apollo-composable/src/useApolloClient.ts']
I took over a Craft CMS project, which I successfully upgraded to the latest version of Craft 5.
When I run the command needed to build the JS and CSS files

npm run dev

I get the following error:
parcel-craft@1.0.0 dev
parcel watch src/js/*.js

 Build failed.
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/ddev/project-name/node_modules/@vue/apollo-composable/src/useApolloClient.ts'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/chris/ddev/project-name/node_modules/@vue/apollo-composable/src/useApolloClient.ts'
}
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/chris/ddev/project-name/node_modules/@vue/apollo-composable/src/useApolloClient.ts'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/chris/ddev/project-name/node_modules/@vue/apollo-composable/src/useApolloClient.ts'
}


The error started happening when I updated some of the packages to newer versions, and I would like to solve this error while using the newer package versions without reverting to a previous repo commit.
When I look at the '@vue/apollo-composable' package contents on my local machine (in /Users/chris/ddev/project-name/node_modules) or on the NPM package website https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/apollo-composable?activeTab=code , there is no /src folder, so it's of no surprise I get the 'no such file or directory' error message.
Here is the package.json file contents:
{
  "name": "parcel-craft",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "source": "src/js/app.js",
  "targets": {
    "default": {
      "distDir": "./web/dist"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel watch src/js/*.js ",
    "build": "parcel build src/js/*.js --dist-dir ./web/dist"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.8.3",
    "@parcel/transformer-vue": "^2.8.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.37",
    "buffer": "^5.5.0",
    "parcel-plugin-html-externals": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "sass": "^1.55.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.10",
    "@imgix/js-core": "^3.6.0",
    "@swc/helpers": "^0.4.3",
    "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.2",
    "dom-slider": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fuse.js": "^6.6.2",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "swiper": "^8.4.4",
    "vue": "3.2.45",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.1.0",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0",
    "zenscroll": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "externals": [
    "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}

I am running node v20.17.0
Edit: appending an answer from the staging ground where they requested I search the codebase for 'src/useApolloClient' & 'useApolloClient.ts'
Codebase search results:
'src/useApolloClient': https://i.imgur.com/iNAU1pJ.png & https://i.imgur.com/mOZdDeY.png
'useApolloClient.ts': https://i.imgur.com/g9ec5bu.png & https://i.imgur.com/EGDhEvB.png
As you can see, all the search results are from package files in the node_modules dir, which of course I do not maintain and cannot edit. I'm not sure how this ever worked before when the files are clearly calling ../src/useApolloClient.ts and there is no /src directory in the @vue/apollo-composable package in the current or previous versions.


The error started happening when I updated some of the packages to newer versions

It's not always possible to update a projects dependencies, sometimes the changes in newer versions will make it difficult, or too time-consuming to do.
Crucially, I see that the package generating the error is beta software:
"@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-beta.1"
In-development software typically brings changes, and updating to newer versions without understanding those changes is often not a seamless experience.
Personally, I'd revert that package to its previous version and then carefully review the release notes for that package, so that you are fully aware of what will change on upgrading and can act accordingly. It may not be possible for you to upgrade that package, your project may have constraints that prevent it.
